# android how to change view from phone to tablet view in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-3.0-honeycomb

Hi I have a Android application that I am trying to run on a tablet in eclipse. However, when I run it I can only open it in a phone view. I went to the properties and changed it to Android 3.1 but that did not fix the problem. Does anyone know the fix here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you need the emulator to show such kind of display, just change the kind of display you need. Go to the `AVD manager` and create a new virtual device:

`Eclipse`: `Window` -> `AVD manager` -> `new`

Choose appropriate Android version. Then for the display choose appropriate skin (e.g. WXGA, which is tablet). After you create this virtual device, you can run your code against it. If the device is still run in portrait mode, you can always flip it using `ctl + f12` to landscape.